# How to add additional htmlattributes in extension for Kendo DatePicker

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I m trying to add html attribute in extension method for kendo's datetime picker

```
    public static DatePickerBuilder Readonly(this DatePickerBuilder builder, bool isReadOnly)
    {
        if (isReadOnly)
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dic.Add("readonly", "readonly");
            builder.HtmlAttributes(dic);
        }

        return builder;
    }
```

The code above is working. But its unnecessary creating dictionary. The `HtmlAttribute` method takes `object` as parameter, how do i make a use of it so  i don't have to create dictionary?

Note: I do not want to use razor syntax to add readonly attribute

**Update 1**
So i solved the above issue by changing the code like below

```
    public static DatePickerBuilder Readonly(this DatePickerBuilder builder, bool isReadOnly)
    {
        if (isReadOnly)
        {
            var comp = builder.ToComponent();
            comp.HtmlAttributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        }

        return builder;
    }
```

However i have to make sure in razor i call `readonly()` extension method as the last method in the chain.

Code blow does not work

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(x => x.Deadline)
              .Format("MM/dd/yyyy")                            
              .Readonly(Model.IsEnabled)
              .HtmlAttributes(new { data_inherit_value = Model.InheritDeadline }))
```

I think its a issue with Kendo date picker control. It overwrites existing htmlattributes

If i change the order and use readonly at the end then code blow works.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(x => x.Deadline)
              .Format("MM/dd/yyyy")                  
              .HtmlAttributes(new { data_inherit_value = Model.InheritDeadline })
              .Readonly(Model.IsEnabled))
```

Answer (score 3):

They actually **clear** the HtmlAttributes collection before they **Merge**, the now **cleared**, HtmlAttributes collection with whatever attributes you are passing in.  I'd call it a bug...

```
/// <summary>Sets the HTML attributes.</summary>
/// <param name="attributes">The HTML attributes.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public virtual TBuilder HtmlAttributes(object attributes)
{
  return this.HtmlAttributes(attributes.ToDictionary());
}

/// <summary>Sets the HTML attributes.</summary>
/// <param name="attributes">The HTML attributes.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public virtual TBuilder HtmlAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> attributes)
{
  this.Component.HtmlAttributes.Clear();
  Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.DictionaryExtensions.Merge(this.Component.HtmlAttributes, attributes);
  return this as TBuilder;
}
```

One way to get around this is to create a MergeHtmlAttributes extension for each control you are using:

```
public static TextBoxBuilder<T> MergeHtmlAttributes<T>(this TextBoxBuilder<T> builder, object attributes)
{
    Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.DictionaryExtensions.Merge(builder.ToComponent().HtmlAttributes, attributes);
    return builder;
}
```

...and in your view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    .Enable(Model.IsViewEditable)
    .MergeHtmlAttributes(new {@class = "k-textbox"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this one, in order do not cumulate multiple readonlies

```
public static DropDownListBuilder Readonly(this DropDownListBuilder builder, bool isReadOnly)
{
    const string Readonly = "readonly";
    var comp = builder.ToComponent();

    comp.HtmlAttributes.Remove(Readonly);
    if (isReadOnly)
        comp.HtmlAttributes.Add(Readonly, isReadOnly);

    return builder;
}
```